# Angular Material Dialog not showing on mobile device

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile-safari, angular-material

I have a strange problem with Angular Material displaying a dialog when testing on mobile (tested on iPhone 5c).

When you click the "Do Something" button in the toolbar it's supposed to pop up a dialog in the middle of the screen, which works perfectly in chrome and chrome's emulation of iPhone 5c.

However when I tested it on an actual mobile device, the dialog box was confined within the menu bar and its height was squashed to fit and the close button inside it didn't work

This a simplified version of my problem just using the default StarterApp with the dialog js code at the bottom. If you run it on a real mobile device, you should be able to see my problem. Thanks for helping!

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="StarterApp">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:300,400,500,700,400italic">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" />
</head>

<body layout="column" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <md-toolbar layout="row">
    <div layout="row" layout-align="start center" class="md-toolbar-tools">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
    <div layout="row" layout-align="end center" class="md-toolbar-tools">
      <md-button ng-click="doSomething($event)" aria-label="Do Something">Do Something</md-button>
    </div>
  </md-toolbar>
  <div layout="row" flex>
    <div layout="column" flex id="content">


    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

  <!-- custom stuff -->
  <style>
    .md-toolbar-tools h1 {
      font-size: inherit;
      font-weight: inherit;
      margin: inherit;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('StarterApp', ['ngMaterial']);

    app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdDialog',
      function($scope, $mdDialog) {
        $scope.data = {};

        $scope.doSomething = function($event) {
          var parentEl = angular.element(document.body);
          $mdDialog.show({
            parent: parentEl,
            targetEvent: $event,
            template: '<md-dialog aria-label="Do Something"><md-dialog-content><p>Hello World</p></md-dialog-content>' +
              '<div class="md-actions"><md-button ng-click="close()">Close</md-button></div></md-dialog>',
            controller: DialogController
          });

          function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
            $scope.close = function() {
              $mdDialog.hide();
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ahh, stackoverflow won't let you run the snippet on their mobile site, but you can if you click "full site" in the footer :)

Comment: as far as I know angular-material is not that tested(is it even being tested?) on iphones(apple devices). I guess you should add a new issue into repository.

Comment: Did you get this fixed? How? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Yeah, I just downloaded the nightly release which had the bug fixes for mobile, but that was nearly a year ago so the official release should have them by now...

Comment: Please provide an answer with that information or delete your question.

Comment: 2021, I'm still having the same issue with some modules of Angular Materials (flex not working and frozen columns of table not working).